# scraping json data with scrapy

Tags: json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the website below I have successfully reached till generating the body .I would like to know how to access the other details like name , rating , title ,description. Below is the code . I would like to figure out how to acess the keys in the response like name, rating , review

code :

```
import scrapy
import json
from pprint import pprint

class nykacr(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nykaa'
    allowed_domains=['nykaa.com']
    start_urls = ["https://www.nykaa.com/gateway-api/products/683166/reviews?pageNo=1&filters=DEFAULT&domain=nykaa"]


    def parse(self,response):
        datas = json.loads(response.body)
```

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to grab the `reviewData` field and iterate it like a list:

for example:

```
import scrapy

class nykacr(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nykaa'
    allowed_domains=['nykaa.com']
    start_urls = ["https://www.nykaa.com/gateway-api/products/683166/reviews?pageNo=1&filters=DEFAULT&domain=nykaa"]


    def parse(self,response):
        for item in response.json()["response"]["reviewData"]:
            yield {
                "id": item["id"],
                "childId": item["childId"],
                "title": item["title"],
                "description": item["description"],
                "name": item["name"],
                "createdOn": item["createdOn"],
                "reviewCreationText": item["reviewCreationText"],
                "likeCount": item["likeCount"],
                "rating": item["rating"],
                "isLikedByUser": item["isLikedByUser"],
                "isBuyer": item["isBuyer"],
            }
```